# Awaitility - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError thrown when trying to run the program from eclipse

Tags: java, awaitility

Awaitility is used for `synchronizing asynchronous operations`. So I'm trying to use it for my automation project to handle the synchronization issues. So I tried with some basic program.

```
import static org.awaitility.Awaitility.*;
import static org.awaitility.Duration.*;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

 public static void main( String[] args )
        {        
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Learning/synchronization/Resources/chromedriver.exe");    
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get("http://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/dynamic-data-loading-demo.html");
            WebElement newUserBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("save"));
         WebElement loadingElement = driver.findElement(By.id("loading"));

            // Get a new User
            newUserBtn.click();

            await().atMost(15,TimeUnit.SECONDS).until(loadingElement::getText, not("Loading..."));
            System.out.println("User profile retrieved");
        }
```

But whenever it encounters the below line, it throws the below exception

```
await().atMost(15,TimeUnit.SECONDS).until(loadingElement::getText, not("Loading..."));
```

Error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/awaitility/Awaitility
    at com.testing.automation.synchronization.App.main(App.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.awaitility.Awaitility
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

And I thought of whether any dependencies got missed out which leads to the below error. But i'm not sure. And I'm using the maven project with Java 8 version.

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.awaitility/awaitility -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.awaitility/awaitility -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.awaitility/awaitility-proxy -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility-proxy</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

[image]

I really don't have a clue why i'm getting this error. 
Could any one please help me out to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your maven pom you are importing the utility only in `test` scope. However, it seems you are trying to run the application in a normal mode not a test mode through using `main`.

Try to remove `<scope>test</scope>` for the first two dependencies from the pom file.

By the way, I did some reading and it looks like this utility is designed for tests only, not production.

Comment: Thanks @admdev -  I removed the <scope>test</scope> from the dependencies. And now it is working fine :)